# How to make a landing page with a full screen image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to make a landing page with an full screen image. Like this: http://startbootstrap.com/templates/stylish-portfolio/

I can figure out the rest of the stuff below it, but how do I go about making the image cover the whole screen?

Comment: you want to make full page like the demo or just the image section ?

Comment: Did you inspect the page? It is all right there

Comment: @ShahRukh just the image section :)

Comment: Just inspect the webpage in your favorite browser's tools suite (take a look at the CSS for .header)

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cZNtv/

Answer (score 1):

it is background for the header tag

if you go to line 153 to 163 in stylish_portfolio.css

```
.header {
display: table;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: url(../img/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;}
```

the backgorund-size is the trick to keep it covering all the screen [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

---edit

height and width should be 100% so the picture would fit the whole screen on any media.

Comment: height and width needed on html,body

Answer (score -1):

You should take a big size image. then

you html will look like

```
    <html>
      <head>
         <title>Landing Page</title>
      </head>
      <body>
         <div class="landingbg">&nbsp;</div>
      </body>
  </html>
```

then css will be

```
.landingbg{
          background: url("img/bg.jpg") no-repeat scroll center center / cover     rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
display: block;
height: 100%;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
     }
```

try this and tell me if there is any issue

Answer (score -1):

You probably need a large HD image for background.

```
html { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

For more detail: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: This is not what he is asking about. He wants to be able to scroll down to other content like in the example

Answer (score -2):

Have JQuery function to get width and height of the end-user screen.

```
var jQueryWidth = $( window ).width();
var jQueryHeight = $( window ).height();
```

Once you have this, set your HTML image width and height attributes.

```
<img src="yourImage.jpg" alt="Alternate text" height="<jQueryWidth>" width="<jQueryHeight>">
```

Comment: A downvote right after less than a second after posting, please let me know if you dislike answers and only expecting comment! :-)

Comment: jQuery is completely unnecessary for this task, and very much overkill.

Comment: @sevenseacat, if you look at very broad-question, CoderBryan have tagged JQuery as well. I don't think its good idea to downvote.

Comment: There is no need for JavaScript to make an element the full size of the page. What happens when the page is resized?

Comment: JQuery support window resize events as well.